# Find the sum of all the primes below two million.My program doesn't work for very big numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, primes

This is my code for finding the sum of primes.It works good with some low numbers but if it's `2000000`(2 million) it never ends.Anybody can help me?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class Problem010{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigInteger sum = new BigInteger("2");

        //for (int i=3; i<2000000; i++) {
        for(int i=3; i<10; i++){
            for (int j=2; j<i; j++){
                if (i % j == 0) 
                    break;
                else if (i == j+1){
                    sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum  = "+sum); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could suggest these 2, 1) instead of running inner loop through 2 to i, run through 2 to sqrt(i).  2) skip for even numbers

Comment: sum of all primes under 2000000 should fit into a `long`

Comment: I am sure, your program takes so much time to finish. So, change your algorithm.

Comment: _It never ends_ for about how many minutes or hour?

Comment: Use the "Eratosthenes sieve" approach to calculate the primes, then sum them. I'd expect that to evaluate in under a second on an "average" PC.

Comment: This is an problem from Project Euler. The idea is to find algorithms, that can calculate the answer "fast", yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your answer is `142913828922` but how?

I just changed your algorithm a little bit:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BigInteger sum = new BigInteger("2");
    boolean isPrime = true;
    for (int i=3; i<2000000; i++) {
    double aa = Math.sqrt((double)i);
        for (int j=2; j<=aa; j++){
            if (i % j == 0){ 
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime){
            sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }
        isPrime = true;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum  = "+sum); 
}
```

instead of going through all the numbers from 2 to i I just go from 2 to sqrt(i) and this improve your code running time a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

@Lrrr, answer is correct. But algorithm can be further optimised. Look at my `isPrime` algorithm. For 2 million you don't need the `BigInteger`.

```
    long sum = 2;// new BigInteger("2");
    for (int i=3; i<2000000; i++) {
        if(isPrime(i)) {
            sum = sum + i;//.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }    
    }
    System.out.println("Sum  = "+sum);
```

Here is isPrime method.

```
 static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    if (n == 2 || n == 3) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((n & 1) == 0 || n % 3 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int sqrtN = (int) Math.sqrt(n) + 1;
    for (int i = 6; i <= sqrtN; i += 6) {// loop 6 step
        if (n % (i - 1) == 0 || n % (i + 1) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right :) there is no need for a class like BigInteger :) +1 for your improvement :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm, it is more efficient then yours.

1) Store all numbers between 2 and N in array and mark them all as prime numbers.

2) Start from X = 2, and mark all its i*X (2X, 3X..), where i is natural number less then or equal N, multipliers as not prime. Do not mark X.

3) Find the next number greater then X which is not marked and repeat the procedure. If there is no such number, stop.

4) Remaining numbers in your array are prime

Something like this:

public static boolean[] findPrimes (int N) {

```
    boolean[] primes = new boolean[N + 1];

    // assume that all numbers are prime within given range
    for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
        primes[i] = true;
    }

    // for all numbers in range, starting from 2
    for (int i = 2; i*i <= N; i++) {

        // mark natural multiples of i as nonprime
        if (primes[i]) {
            for (int j = i; i*j <= N; j++) {
                primes[i*j] = false;
            }
       }

 return primes;
}
```

5) Iterate over returned primes and sum indexes of TRUE values

Comment: I think this will be very inefficient as we need to store 2million digit all at once

Comment: The bit complexity of the algorithm is O(n (\log n) (\log \log n)) bit operations with a memory requirement of O(n). Its fairly efficient given enough memory.

Answer (score 2):

An efficient solution could be to use [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to find out which number is prime below 2,000,000 (or any other number), and than post-process and sum them all:

```
    int n = 2000000;
    boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[n];
    //preprocess - set up the array
    for (int i = 2; i<n;i++) isPrime[i] = true;
    //run sieve:
    for (int i = 2; i < (int) Math.sqrt(n) + 1; i++) { 
        if (isPrime[i]) {
            for (int j = 2; j*i < n; j++) isPrime[i*j] = false;
        }
    }
    //sum primes:
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) { 
        if (isPrime[i]) sum+=i;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

As opposed to checking for each number at a time if it is prime or not (which takes `O(sqrt(n))` - and by doing it for all numbers you get `O(nsqrt(n))`, in here you aggregate knowledge from previous iterations, effectively lowering the complexity to `O(nloglog(n))`, which is significantly faster for large enough values of `n`.

This comes at a cost of `O(n)` additional space.

Comment: actually, the last `for` loop is not necessary :)

Comment: @PhamTrung It can be done inplace in the siece method, but there is little point for it performance wise, and has a lot of point for it readbility wise.

Answer (score 0):

I developed my own solution and it completes in 700 milliseconds to find all below 2 million.

I use the iterative method but I just stop looking for the numbers greater than **(n/i)+1** where **n** is the number being checked if it is prime and **i** is the number in the iterative loop to see if it is a divisor.

```
public void run () {
    long sumOfPrimes = 2;
    int maxNumber = 2000000;
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 3; i <= maxNumber; i = i+2) {
        if(isPrimeOptimized(i)){
            sumOfPrimes = sumOfPrimes + i;
            counter ++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("num of primes is " + counter);
    System.out.println("sum of primes is " + sumOfPrimes);
}

private boolean isPrimeOptimized(int n){
    int limitToDivide = n;
    for(int i=2;i<=limitToDivide && i<n;i++){
        if(n%i == 0)
            return false;
        else
            limitToDivide = (n/i) + 1;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So far no one has actually implemented the Sieve correctly.  Double check the wikipedia page and pay attention to how you are looping through the numbers.  Without any optimizations using an array of int (or booleans) it should take only a few seconds in Java.

Comment: If you think the two sieve answers are incorrect, please be more specific.